# How do I get a function to identify a variable I've identified

Tags: python, loops, exception, methods

My program is trying to create a program that identifies a program that includes 3 functions: 1 to identify the length, 1 to make sure they're are not any spaces and 1 that makes sure that the program checks that you're using at least 1 number and letter. I basically have almost everything that I want, I'm just not understanding how to put them together and work cohesively.

In the passlength function, I get the correct outcome if I were to add "password = input("Enter password: ")" at the beginning of the line. However, I'm trying to do that within the main function. Then it should collapse in that function to check whether or not you have the correct amount of characters. No less than 6 characters, but no more than 15.

In the next function, I'm trying to make sure no spaces are in the password, however no matter what I do it keeps rendering false.

I've tried the same thing as above with the "isalpha" and "isdigit" functions as well. However, I'm unsure how it would check from 0 to 15 make sure that at least 1 digit and 1 alphabetical letter are used.

But my overall concern is how to use a variable in my main function then transfer that don't do my subfunctions for results, then using an if statement loop it back in case your password isn't safe.

```
def passLength():
    password = input("Enter password: ")
    if len(password) > 5 and len(password) < 15:
        print("Password Length - Confirmed")
    else:
        print("Password length - Invalid, please try again")
        passLength()


def passSpace():
    password = input("Enter password: ")
    passwordSpace = password.isspace()
    print(passwordSpace)

def main():
    password = input("Enter password: ")
    passLength()
```

Comment: You need to have the `input` statement in the main program, then pass that variable as a argument to the other functions.  And they shouldn't call each other like this; each function should serve one specific purpose, and the mainline code will call those functions and decide what to do with their response.

Comment: Remember that `isspace` checks if the entire string consists of white space.  You need something like `' ' in password`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the kind of organization you need.  The validation functions just do validation.  It is up to the caller to decide what to do with the information.

```
def passLength(password):
    return 5 < len(password) < 15

def passSpace(password):
    return ' ' not in password

def main():
    while True:
        password = input("Enter password: ")
        if not passLength(password):
            print("Too short or too long.  Try again.")
        elif not passSpace(password):
            print("No spaces allowed.  Try again.")
        else:
            print( "Success" )
            break

main()
```

Comment: I appreciate you! So if I wanted to utilize the isdigit function could I do: def passDigit(password):
    return password.isdigit()

Comment: Yes, but remember `isdigit` returns true only if the ENTIRE STRING consists of digits.  Your code needs to be more complicated.

Comment: would there be a way to check if somewhere in the password there is at least one digit? This would also include if there was one letter as well using the 'isalpha' function

Comment: You have to check each letter.  Something like `if any(c.isdigit() for c in password):`, which you could do with a loop, if you haven't learned any/all yet.